# Google Docs with JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-docs-api

I tried this [plugin](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/394-Google-Docs-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html) for reading pdf documents in the currently opened browser. It greatly works on the regular browser, but when I open it from the mobile it doesn't fit in the screen.

So, is there a method to display the document correctly on the mobile ...

Is there something like this is Jquery Mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

probably you might be interested in the Google Docs viewer?
this is the syntax:

```
    http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=URLTOFILE
```

[see an example here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://puravidaapps.com/images/snippets/WooHoo.pdf)

for more info [see also this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dVoqTTVu9U4)